# Using cursor with information_schema

Tags: mysql

I have the following code:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dropAll $$

CREATE PROCEDURE dropAll()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE constraint_name VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE table_name CHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO constraint_name, table_name;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    select table_name, constraint_name;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END$$
call dropAll()$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It should print the name of the tables and the constraints. But the output I get looks like

```
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
table_name  constraint_name
NULL    NULL
```

If I use the same code on any database other than information_schema I get expected output. Is there something different about database information_schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefix your variable names to distinguish them from the column names.

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dropAll $$

CREATE PROCEDURE dropAll()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE v_constraint_name VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE v_table_name CHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO v_constraint_name, v_table_name;
    IF v_done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    select v_table_name, v_constraint_name;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END$$
call dropAll()$$
DELIMITER ;
```